# How can I use UpdateCursor in AGOL layers?

Tags: python, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-online, arcgis-python-api

I'm all new to Python, and 'Im stuck with a problem:

Is it possible to use UpdateCursor on Feature Layers in AGOL?

I am trying something like this:

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS

gis = GIS("https://arcgis.com", "xxxxxx")

import arcpy

fs=gis.content.search(query="title:xxx, owner:xxxx", max_items=5000,)

kort = fs.layer[0]

fields = ["Fabrikat", "Entreprenør"]

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(kort, fields) as cursor:

    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] == "ABB":
               row[1] = "3"
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

but its popping up with this error:

> RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         2 lag = query_result1
>         3 fields = ["Fabrikat", "Entreprenør"]
>   ----> 4 with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(lag, fields) as cursor:
>         5     for row in cursor:
>         6         if row[0] == "ABB":

RuntimeError: 'in_table' is not a table or a featureclass

How can I make the cursor "eat" the layer?

Comment: You've tagged this with 10.2, but you're using Python3.

Answer (score 3):

The error is saying the UpdateCursor does not like the input, it is NOT a "table or featureclass".

If you do a type on your layers, you'll see its an object specific to the ArcGIS Python API. And you're trying to use an arcpy cursor that wants either a table or feature class.

```
l = f.layers[0]
type(l)
>> arcgis.features.layer.FeatureLayer
```

However, the Cursors appear to accept a URL to a feature service. So you can modify your code slightly and use the URL:

```
url = kort.url
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(url, fields) as cursor:

    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] == "ABB":
               row[1] = "3"
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

My testing shows you do NOT need to provide authentication with a private Feature Service (as long as you've created your GIS object as the owner of the service). However, you can also try this workflow to pass in a token.

```
g = GIS("https://www.arcgis.com", USER, PASS)

token = g._con.token

fs = g.content.search(query="title:My Service", max_items=10)
url = fs[0].layers[0].url
print(url)

featureset = arcpy.FeatureSet()
authenticatedURL = url + "?token={}".format(token)
featureset.load(authenticatedURL)

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(authenticatedURL , "*") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = "hello"
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: That is brilliant ..! But instead another error appears :RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-8573a7a88453> in <module>
      2 fields = ["Fabrikat", "Entreprenør"]
      3 with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(url, fields) as cursor:
----> 4     for row in cursor:
      5         if row[0] == "ABB":
      6                row[1] = "3"

RuntimeError: ERROR: code:400, , Unable to perform query. Please check your parameters., Bad syntax in request. ....What could that be?

Comment: That may come down to how you're running the code. I did all my testing inside ArcGIS Pro's Python Window. It might be how you're authenticated? Or maybe its the fields (_Entreprenør_) using special characters? You may need to set an encoding? There are so many things it might be, its very hard to say.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time. When I run it inside ArcgisPro, it works fine, but I would like to run it as a stand-alone script.  It seems not to be the encoding, I get the same result on another field without danish letters. But maybe its the wrong way of doing it,  there is probably a better method when working with Agol... but the cursor method is more understandable for a non-pogrammer like me...

Comment: I added another bit of code that you can follow to authenticate the FS using a token when in the _arcpy_ world. However, I could edit a private service that I owned. So I'm not sure if this is the problem or not. Note, I'm using ArcGIS Pro 2.5. Which version are you using?

Comment: I just see this now! It works! Thanks. I dont know why I need to pass a token , but its works! You made my day - thanks!

Comment: Hi again. I can now update the "normal" fields vith this piece of code, thanks! However, there is a problem with fields with domains. For example a field with domains 11 = Steel, 12 = Cupper etc doesnt react to neiter the domain code (11 ) nor the value ("Steel", Cupper.. etc) . Is there a way you can come about that?

Comment: I dont know without testing. I'd ask a new question specific to that.